How to Design a User Registration Process Across Multiple Tables (Member and Auth) While Adhering to SOLID Principles?
I am currently developing a registration process using JWT for authentication. In my application, I have two tables: Member (which stores user personal information, owned items, etc.) and Auth (which stores username and password). My current structure involves:
Member: Managed by MemberController, MemberService, and MemberRepository
Auth: Managed by AuthController, AuthService, and AuthRepository
The current folder structure is as follows:
├── Member
│   ├── MemberController
│   ├── MemberService
│   └── Member
│
├── Security
│   ├── AuthController
│   ├── AuthService
│   └── Auth

Since the registration process requires creating records in both Member and Auth tables, what would be the best way to design this to adhere to SOLID principles? Are there any design patterns you recommend for handling this scenario in a clean, modular way?
This question clearly explains your context and requirements while asking for advice on both SOLID principles and design patterns to improve your registration process.
I am also considering building "RegistrationService + Controller"
@Service
public class RegistrationService {
    private final MemberService memberService;
    private final AuthService authService;

    public RegistrationService(MemberService memberService, AuthService authService) {
        this.memberService = memberService;
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    public void register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        // Auth 정보 생성
        Auth auth = new Auth(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
        authService.save(auth);

        // Member 정보 생성
        Member member = new Member(request.getEmail(), auth);
        memberService.save(member);
    }
}

I wanted to put the AuthService into MemberService but seems not so right

There are many ways to solve this.  I'll give you the simplest:
Wrap the whole thing in a transaction, and don't worry about services interacting with each other, that's normal.  Worry if the number of services one service interacts gets to 10 or so, then it's probably time for a refactor.
You could expand this by going full DDD and use domain events, but that's a pretty significant structural change to your app and the juice may not be worth the squeeze.
